# is 3g on or off

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

is there any API available to detect state of 3G ie on or off state through codes.

Answer (score 1):

This question is almost a duplicate of the question I have linked to below - which should tell you most of what you need to know:

[How to check for an active Internet connection on iOS or OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk)

Comment: Thax...but that code is not sufficient.if provides wifi or not. i wanna detect if 3G on or off. ******** setting-->network--->enabled3G->YES/No.. detecting this??

Comment: I understand. I'm not sure if this is possible. Perhaps someone else can shine some light!